# How to get the time difference in seconds between two db column status (or events)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the time difference in seconds in my database between two events. On the database,  the users table has different columns but I'm working with the status column. If a user places an order on our website the status column shows "pending" and, if it is confirmed by our agents it then switches to "success". I'm trying to get the time difference (in secs) between when it shows pending and when it shows success.

NB: I'll be glad if anyone can explain the time() function in PHP with an example.

Comment: The manual has `time()` examples, http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php. Is there a specific issue you are having with it? So you are looking for the time it takes for a record to update?

Comment: Yes Chris. The time it takes to update a record. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I dont think you can do that with the DB. You could store the `microtime` before and after the update on the PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's `unix_timestamp()` function.  Assuming that your table has two records for the two events, and there is a column called `eventTime`, then two queries like the following can give you the two values which are the respective number of seconds since Epoch.   You can subtract the latter by the former and get the time difference

```
select unix_timestamp(eventTime) ... where status='pending'

select unix_timestamp(eventTime) ... where status='success'
```

**Update**

After re-reading your question, I guess your DB design is that there is only one row for the whole life cycle of the transaction (from `pending` to `success`).  In this case, if all three parties (the agent who updates the status to `pending`, the agent who updates the status to `success`, and the agent who needs to find the time difference between the two events) involved are the same thread, then you can keep the two event time in memory and simply compute the difference.

However, I think it is more likely that the three parties are two or three different threads.  In this case, I think you must have some mechanism to pass the knowledge (of the first event time) from one thread to another.  This can be done by way of adding a new column called `lastUpdateTime`, or by adding a new table for the purpose of time tracking.

By the way, if you use the second approach, I think [MySQL Trigger](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx) may be useful for you (so that whenever the table gets updated, it trigger another command to update the second table which is used solely to keep track of event time of elapsed time).  This approach allows you to not changing the original table but just add a new table.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I have two questions. First, don't you think a simple if and else PHP statement can help get the time between the two records? [Note that the events will update in one column (i.e for a user, it will update in a cell, from "pending" to "success")].

Comment: Second, you talked about adding a new column on that same table to show lastupdate time. How do I implement this? The trigger ish looks complicated. Thanks

Comment: The time difference is t2-t1.  If the updater is the same programming thread, then you can code it so that it remembers t1 (e.g. in memory) before the first update.  If not, then somehow the information about t1 must be passed from the first updater to the second updater, who can then compute the difference.

Comment: You can use MySQL `alter table`.  See more here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table-examples.html